# Why does my Bootstrap input not align right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why does my Bootstrap input not align right (=> see 3rd input with placeholder='Does not align right')?
The td table element has a style which defines the alignment...
When I remove the style element from the td element at set the input style text-align=right, it is still left aligned.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well" style="width:840px">
            <table class='table borderless' style="width:800px">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" style="width:300px;margin-bottom:0px" type="text" name="input1" placeholder="Input 1">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" style="width:300px;margin-bottom:0px" type="text" name="input2" placeholder="Input 2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" style="width:300px;margin-bottom:0px" type="text" name="input3" placeholder="Does not align right">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does my Bootstrap input not align right?

Because `.form-control` will have `display: block` from bootstrap.min.css. As proof of this, if you make it an `inline-block` again it'll work:

```css
.form-control { display: inline-block !important; }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well" style="width:840px">
            <table class='table borderless' style="width:800px">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" style="width:300px;margin-bottom:0px" type="text" name="input1" placeholder="Input 1">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" style="width:300px;margin-bottom:0px" type="text" name="input2" placeholder="Input 2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" style="width:300px;margin-bottom:0px" type="text" name="input3" placeholder="Does not align right">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What you probably really want is your controls to behave like that straight away. To do so make sure to utilize Bootstrap's `form-inline`, e.g. like this:

```
<div class="row form-inline">
```

Note that this affects the first row of inputs too. If you move the `form-inline` to a another spot you could choose to prevent that from happening.

Comment: And why does the <hr style="widdth:100px"> tag also does not aline right after preferring your suggestion when I place it below the last input?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you're perhaps asking a new question? There is no `hr` in your posted question. At any rate, it's probably for a similar reason: a `hr` tends to be a *block* element, thus taking up the entire width. If you set an explicit width the actual visualized line might become `100px`, but the block that the `hr` element ecompasses is full-width thus having no notion of "text-align".

Comment: As mentioned, the `hr` will visually be 100px wide but will continue to take up the full width of it's containing element because the remaining width becomes an auto-calculated amount of `margin`. Use developer tools in Chrome or FF to inspect the `hr` and you will see the margin that gets added when setting a specific width when the width is less than the containing element.

Answer (score 3):

That's because your input has it's `display` property set to `block` via the `.form-control` class. Block level elements will take up the whole width of their containing element. Even if a width is set, the remaining space is taken up by margin.

To get the input to align the way you would like change the `display` value to `inline-block` or add the class `.pull-right` to the input.

```css
.form-control {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm pull-right">
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap specially set `width: 100%` property to the `.form-control` to make the life easier and handle such things with [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

*You can go with the following **solution***

**HTML Markup**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 is-centered">
    <div class="well well-form">
     <!-- Two inline input fields per row -->
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
       <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="input1" placeholder="Input 1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
       <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="input2" placeholder="Input 2">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row has-border">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
       <!-- Single input fields per row (pushed to the right) -->
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="input3" placeholder="align to right">
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Helpers (optional)**

*SCSS*

```
[class*="col-"] {
 &.is-centered {
    float: none;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  } 
}

.well-form {
  > .row {
    padding-top: 8px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
}
```

*CSS*

```
[class*="col-"].is-centered {
  float: none;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.well-form > .row {
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.well-form .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/details/ZYgNqy/)

**Couple of things to notice:**

- `<table>` is not a good approach in this case
- inline `style="` to HTML tags is not good at all (even if its a demo)

Hope this helps